# Invalid syntax error on an elif statement

Tags: python

```
elif choice == "2":
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    score = int(input("What score did you get? ")
    entry = (score, name)
    scores.append(entry)
    scores.sort(reverse=True)
    scores = scores[:10]
```

Why is `entry = (score, name)` coming up as `Invalid syntax error`?

Comment: Count the number of parentheses on the line before, you are missing the `)` on `int(`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing closing paren:

```
int(input("What score did you get? ")) #  <-  missing a closing paren
```

Comment: Ah stupid error. Thanks

Comment: @Matt, no worries  it happens, it is often the line before that is the culprit

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting a `)` at the end of `score = int(input("What score did you get? ")`. It should be `score = int(input("What score did you get? "))`